# Can't locate an href element with selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

So this is  the element i want to click:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="logged_time" id="logged_2021-09-01" presence_id="q25474p2842324" user="haha" date="2021-09-01" worked="8:00" user_ad="hahaha" token="irrelevant" action="log">0:00</a>
```

Can't use the `href` since it's the same with many other elements, what I want is to click it by it's id but my code doesn't work:
this is my code:

```
browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="logged_2021-09-01"]').click()
```

An this is the error:

> Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="logged_2021-09-01"]"}

Update:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IdTXX.png)

Update 2:
My code works, the thing is that I was trying to run it with the IDLE console. I thought that once you have opened the browser by calling `browser = webdriver.Chrome()`, then you can navigate everywhere manually while keeping the browser object viable for use.

Comment: Can you share bit more HTML code ?

Comment: I added a image, is it enough?

Comment: Provide enough wait to load the table element properly. You can try explicit wait like WebDriverWait for the same.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following code. It will try to find the `<a>` tag specifically and search the id starting with "logged_". The id will probably change each  day you log in, so not hardcoding the date might save you some time in the future. Also use a WebDriverWait to avoid searching for the element before the page has been loaded. Else the element will not be found, since the page/element hasn't loaded yet.

```
try: 
    xpath = '//a[contains(@id, "logged_")]'
    WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, xpath)))
              
    element = browser.find_element_by_xpath(xpath)

    element.click()

except:
    # Ideally you catch each error separately; TimeoutException, NoSuchElementException, ...
    pass
```